# Create users in Factory Girl with OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, omniauth, factory-bot

I am currently creating an application that uses OmniAuth to create and authenticate users. I am encountering problems during testing due to Factory Girl being unable to generate users without OmniAuth.

I have several different ways to get factory girl to create users with omniauth but none have been successful.

I have added the following 2 lines to my spec_helper file

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true \\ allows me to fake signins
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter, { :uid => '12345', :info => { :nickname => 'Joe Blow' }})
```

current factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    provider "twitter"
    sequence(:uid) { |n| "#{n}" }
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Person_#{n}" }
  end
end
```

The following test currently fails because no user is being generated

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }

describe "registering" do

  it "should increment" do
    expect do
      click_button 'register'
    end.to change(user.rounds, :count).by(1)
end
```

How should I change my factories/tests in order to get Factory Girl to create test users with OmniAuth?

Edit: I used the [RailsCast guide to setup Omniauth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth),

```
#create function inside user.rb
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
  end
end
```

hopefully also useful

```
#create inside the session_controller
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) ||    User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
end
```

Comment: Is there more information that I could provide to help you guys help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to do the following somewhere in the test setup?

request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter]

If you did, is it possible the user's UID doesn't match the mock uid?

You can try changing the factory definition from `sequence(:uid) { |n| "#{n}" }` to `uid '12345'`.